# Apply a function to several elements at once

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

When I apply the same function to several elements, I usually do the following:

```
var func = function(elem) {
  elem.style.color = 'red';
};

var p = document.querySelector('p');
var div = document.querySelector('div');

func(p);
func(div);
```

I was wondering if there is an easy way to apply this function to two (or more) elements at once ? Eg :

```
func(p, div); // Apply my function to both elements at once
```

Comment: Yes, that's what `forEach` does: `[p, div].forEach(func)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of `arguments`:

```
var func = function() {
    var args = [].slice.apply(arguments);

    args.forEach(function (elem) {
        elem.style.color = 'red';
    });
};
```

Call it like you wanted:

```
func(p, div);
```

On a side note, there is a functionality called "rest parameter" planned in ECMAScript 6 that allows for just what you had in mind, take a look [here](http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2013/03/es6-and-rest-parameter.html).

Comment: Well, I doubt if the OP is interested in just rewriting that one function to work with multiple arguments. He's looking for a general solution to writing/rewriting functions that perform some task (defined by an underlying function) across a set of inputs. Also, minor point, but as long you're doing the `[].slice.apply(arguments)` thing, instead of storing the results in an extra variable and then calling `forEach` on it, you can just do `[].forEach.call(arguments, ...` directly.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for :) Didn't know about 'rest', seems very promising.

Comment: Rest parameters are more compact and readable, but basically are nothing more than syntactic sugar around the `arguments` object, eliminating the need for the `[].slice.apply(arguments)` gobbledygook.

Answer (score 2):

#### Transforming the function so it returns itself

By transforming the function so it returns itself, you can use the syntax

```
func(p)(div)
```

To make this work, you'll need to arrange for `func` to return itself.

```
function selfify(fn) {
    return function self() {
        fn.apply(this, arguments);
        return self;
    };
}
```

Then

```
funcx = selfify(func);
funcx(p)(div);
```

#### Transforming the function so it is called on each argument

If you would prefer the `func(p, div)` syntax, write the following kind of transformer, which creates a function which calls an underlying function on each of its arguments:

```
function repeatify(fn) {
    return function() {
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(arguments, fn, this);
    };
}
```

Then

```
funcy = repeatify(func);
funcy(p, div);
```

This obviously won't work well if the underlying function takes two or more parameters.

In ES6, using rest parameters, the above can be written somewhat more simply as

```
function repeatify(fn) {
    return function(...args) {
        [...args].forEach(fn, this);
    };
}
```

#### Real simple solution

If all the above functional-style programming is too much to wrap your head around, all you really need to do is:

```
[p, div].forEach(func);
```

Comment: @Mastah I guess it's too much to hope that folks would have an appreciation for functional programming style, or functions transforming functions in useful ways. As it was, you got an answer which basically told you to write a loop over the arguments. I'm hoping that the part you didn't know was how to loop across arguments, not how to write the loop in the first place. :-)

Comment: Exactly! I'm ok with loops ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could combine some of the great answers here to come up with a *functionnal programming* code easily reusable :

```
var f = function (applyTo) {
    var makeArray = function(arrayLike) {
        return Array.prototype.slice.call(arrayLike);
    };
    return function () {
        var args = makeArray(arguments),
            elements = [];
        args.forEach(function (selector) {
            var newElements = makeArray(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
            console.log(newElements);
            elements = elements.concat(newElements);
        });
        elements.forEach(applyTo);
    }
};

var redify = function (elem) {
    elem.style.color = '#F00';
}

var underline = function (elem) {
    elem.style.textDecoration = 'underline';
}

var overline = function (elem) {
    elem.style.textDecoration = 'overline';
}

f(redify)('div', 'p');

f(underline)('div.test2');

f(overline)('p.test2');
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/laruiss/gr6jjvnt/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
var elms = document.querySelectorAll('p, div'); // css selector to match both p & div
var func = function(elem) {
    elem.style.color = 'red';
};

forEach.call(elms, func);
```

Comment: This changes the semantics of the OP's question. He was applying the color to the first `p` and first `div`. You're applying it to all of them. In any case, I doubt it he was looking for a more efficient way to find the elements to change the color of, but rather a way to transform the function to apply to multiple elements at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Consider combining a basic loop from the previous answers and the use of classes instead of querySelector.

Thus you could assign the needed classed to all your element that you'll need to pass through the function and then just call the function with them:

```
var func = function (elem) {
    for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
        elem[i].style.color = 'red';
    }
};

func(document.getElementsByClassName("yourClass"));
```

Answer (score -1):

The right way to do is through the use of classes.

```
<p class="myClass"></p>
<div class="myClass"></div>
```

Then in your javascript when you wish to change the color of these two elements, simply do:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass");

for(var i=0; i<elems.length; i++){
    func(elem[i]);
}
```

It'll be useful for long run when you have large number of elements, organizing them in classes based on your needs is the way to go.

Comment: This is answering a different question. The OP was not looking for a way to find the elements to apply a color to, he was looking for a way to apply color to multiple elements at the same time.